# Call easy_install apps from java with ProcessBuilder/RunTime

Tags: java, macos

The title doesn't really explain my question, but I don't know how to ask it in a better way. So, basicly, I'm writing a app that uses the program livestreamer. I installed it on my mac using: `easy_install -U livestreamer` . So far, so good, it works when I write `livestream` on my terminal. Now, my issue is that when I try to call it on java:

```
    public static void runLiveStreamer(String channel, String quality) throws IOException{


    String[] cmd  = new String[]{"livestreamer", "twitch.tv/"+channel, quality};
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line=null;
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);    
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "livestreamer": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at livestream.runLiveStreamer(livestream.java:12)
```

I know the code works, because if I replace the `String[] cmd  = new String[]{"livestreamer", "twitch.tv/"+channel, quality};` with, for example, `ls`, it outputs without any problem. This is my first time messing with this kinds of stuff, so my error is probably a really newbie one. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`livestreamer` is not in your Java process’s path.

Every Windows and Unix operating system’s execution environment has a concept of a program path.  The path is an environment variable (named `PATH` in all operating systems except Windows, which uses `Path`).  It contains a list of directories, separated by colons `:`, except on Windows where they’re separated by semicolons (`;`).

As with any environment variable, each running process may have its own path defined, and child processes usually inherit it from their parent process.

Whenever you try to run a program without any directory separators (for instance, trying to run `ls` instead of `/bin/ls`), the system will look for that program in each directory in the path.

In your terminal, your PATH contains a directory which has `livestream` in it.  When you run your Java process, you have a different PATH, one which does not include the directory which contains `livestream`.

The easiest solution is to refer to `livestream` by its absolute file name, thus making the system execution path irrelevant:

```
String[] cmd  = { "/usr/bin/livestreamer", "twitch.tv/" + channel, quality };
```

`/usr/bin/livestreamer` is just an example.  I don’t know where livestreamer was actually installed on your system.

To find it, do `which livestreamer` in your terminal.  That should tell you the absolute location of it.  (I think in Windows, the command would be `where livestreamer`.)

Comment: I though about that, but I had no idea that Runtime used java path, well, makes sense now, it's working! Thanks!